# VBA - Multifield Dropdown Box Search Query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a dropdown check box that you can manually select different options in it that you would like to query for.

**What I want to do:**

I want to make a search query form that would allow to user to SELECT MULTIPLE information from a dropdown list. Afterwards I parse a specific column in the master table for this information.

**The Issue:**

I have a drop down multifield combo list that allows for users to select MULTIPLE options to search for. An image should better showcase it:
[Search Query - Select items you want to search for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq1Lp.png)

I do not know how to make the Technology field work within my SQL Query.

**The Query:**

Me.Technology holds a string that the user chose in the Form. I.E within the image provided above the string would be "Console, PC, Web".

EveryTable.Technology is a list that contains every option.

```
Private Sub button_Click()
    Dim SQLAll As String
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim Sector As String
    Sector = Me.txtSector

    If Sector = "All" Then
        Sector = " "
    End If

    SQL = "SELECT * " _
        & "FROM EveryTable " _
        & "WHERE EveryTable.Sector LIKE '*" & Sector & "*' " _
        & "AND EveryTable.Technology.Value LIKE '*" & Me.Technology & "*' " 

    Me.subformMain.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.subformMain.Requery
End Sub
```

Below is an image that shows the master table with all the information. Providing an idea of what is held in the cell I am attempting to reference in my Query.

[Master table that holds all information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QFyy.png)

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

Based on the images I provided, the expected output will provide me a SUBFORM in the MAIN form of EVERY row who's 'Technology' column contains the string 'Console, PC, Web'.
As seen in the picture below, my expected output did not return to me what I wanted after I hit the Enter button.

[Expected Output Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh2mJ.png)

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!*  I don't understand what you're asking, and the image is no help at all.  Could you please take a few minutes to expand on what you have (ie., sample data), what you need to do (ie, sample of expected output), and what you've tried. I don't know the structure of your database but `EveryTable.Technology.Value` doesn't look like a valid way to refer to a field.  Also, see "[ask]" as well as tips on creating a [mcve] ie, crop unneeded parts of the image), plus [these tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/) for asking questions, from the site's top user.

Comment: Thanks. Is it easier to understand now? I hope the images make it crystal clear as to what I want it to do

Answer (score 0):

Some great person, user "Tim Williams", answered my question but deleted his answer. Anyway here it is for future reference.

```
Private Sub button_Click()

    Dim SQL As String, sep As String, arr, t
    Dim Sector As String

    Sector = Me.txtSector
    If Sector = "All" Then Sector = ""

    SQL = "SELECT * FROM EveryTable WHERE " & _
      "EveryTable.Sector LIKE '*" & Sector & "*'"

    If Len(Me.Technology) > 0 Then

        SQL = SQL & " AND ("
        sep = ""
        arr = Split(Me.Technology, ",")

        For Each t In arr
            SQL = SQL & sep & " EveryTable.Technology.Value LIKE '*" & Trim(t) & "*' "
            sep = vbCrLf & " AND "
        Next t
        SQL = SQL & ")"

    End If
    Debug.Print SQL

    Me.subformMain.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.subformMain.Requery

End Sub
```